# Youtube Subscribe Button Event

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-channels

How can I catch an event when a user subscribes to my Youtube Channel on my site?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an image, button, or banner in order to record the action(click) that lands them on the YouTube subscription page.

```
<p> <a href="DOMAIN" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ChannelSubcription', 'SUBSCRIBED', 'SUBSCRIPTION');"><img src="Title.jpg"></a></p>
```

If you're trying to record the action from an embedded player you'll need to use YouTube's API - it would be wise to reference their beta API. You could also use the [custom iframe subscribe button for your channel](http://www.labnol.org/internet/youtube-subscribe-button/18089/) and record without having them exit your site.