# Youtube Subscribe button onevent

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

The goal is to redirect the page after the Youtube Subscribe button is clicked. I'm using the code straight from the [YouTube Dev Site](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button)

Problem:  Clicking of button triggers no action.

The code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data-layout="default" data-count="default" data-onytevent="onYtEvent"></div>

  <script>
    function onYtEvent(payload) {
      if (payload.eventType == 'subscribe') {
        alert("Hello World!")
      } else if (payload.eventType == 'unsubscribe') {
        alert("Bye World!")
      }
    }
  </script>
  <script src="jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try doing window.location.href = "http://http://www.yoururl.com"  ... (i am not sure)

Comment: Note: i've also tried a simple alert but that didnt work either.

Comment: include the jquery script and place it below before your `</body>` tag

Comment: I think this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283159/youtube-subscribe-button-event?rq=1

Comment: jquery was already linked.

Comment: Looks like this is an issue on Google's end https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5707